# SmartGWT Application not loading on latest Firefox 50 version

Tags: firefox, smartgwt

I am using `SmartGWT 6.0` for my application. Currently my firefox and chrome got updated to latest version (`firefox 50,chrome 55`). Its working fine in chrome but in firefox my application is not at all loading its throwing `ISC_Core,ISC_*` related error.I want to solve this issue.Image is attached here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved after taking the latest smartgwt jar
(I was using Version `v11.0p_2016-07-23/LGPL Deployment - 2016-07-23`) replaced with `LGPL Deployment 2017-01-19 jar`.Its a `smartgwt` issue.